# Get the highest role of a user across all the organizations he is member of

Tags: performance, scala

I have a function that looks like this:

```
def getMaxUserLevelByUserId(userId: Muid)(
      implicit connection: Connection): Option[OrganizationMembership.Level.Value] = {
    val organizationMemberships = getAllByUserId(userId)

    if (organizationMemberships.exists(_.level == OrganizationMembership.Level.Admin)) {
      Some(OrganizationMembership.Level.Admin)
    } else if (organizationMemberships.exists(_.level == OrganizationMembership.Level.Member)) {
      Some(OrganizationMembership.Level.Member)
    } else if (organizationMemberships.exists(_.level == OrganizationMembership.Level.Guest)) {
      Some(OrganizationMembership.Level.Guest)
    } else {
      None
    }
  }
```

The gets the highest role of a user across all the organizations he is member of. As you can see, the function is pretty straightforward and works. However, it has a complexity of O(*n*<sup>3</sup>). I was wondering if there is a way to get it to O(*n*) or at least a bit lower?

Comment: I don't see the \$\mathcal O(n^3)\$ complexity. I only see \$\mathcal O(3n)\$, which by definition is equivalent to \$\mathcal O(n)\$.

Comment: hmmm...  You are so right!  I am usually not that slow. )))) Sorry..

Comment: It was a fun exercise though :)

Comment: What are the other possible levels? Or are `Admin`, `Member`, and `Guest` the only possible levels? If so, is the last `else` simply there in case the list is empty?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're doing could be expressed thusly.

```
import scala.util.Try

val levelMap = Map(...

Try(getAllByUserId(userId).maxBy(org => levelMap(org.level)).level).toOption
```

It's worth noting that this will also catch any exceptions thrown by `levelMap`. (Maybe a new level is encountered not yet included in `levelMap`.) That might or might not be considered a good thing.

You can unpack it some to avoid the `try`/`catch` overhead hidden inside the `Try` type.

```
if (organizationMemberships.isEmpty)
  None
else
  Some(organizationMemberships.maxBy(om => levelMap(om.level)).level)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is what I did. Not sure if that's the best way to go.

```
def getMaxUserLevelByUserId(userId: Muid)(
      implicit connection: Connection): Option[OrganizationMembership.Level.Value] = {
    val organizationMemberships = getAllByUserId(userId)

    if (organizationMemberships.nonEmpty) {

      val levelMap = Map(
          OrganizationMembership.Level.Guest -> 0,
          OrganizationMembership.Level.Member -> 1,
          OrganizationMembership.Level.Admin -> 2
      )

      val maxLevel = organizationMemberships.foldLeft(OrganizationMembership.Level.Guest) {
        (level, organizationMembership) =>
          if (levelMap(organizationMembership.level) > levelMap(level)) {
            organizationMembership.level
          } else {
            level
          }
      }

      Some(maxLevel)

    } else {

      None

    }
  }
```

The idea behind the code above, is the fact that we are iterating through the collection only once, regardless of the collection size. 
The `levelMap` was created strictly for the reason of easier comparison.

The cool thing about `foldLeft` in this case is that we don't need to create mutable variables while iterating through the collection and it is actually very short and quite readable code.

Comment: Self answers are allowed, but code dumps (with no explanation of the motivations behind your changes) are not valid answers. Furthermore, if  you are seeking a review of this revised code, then you should make it the new question instead (assuming that no other answers have been posted in the meantime).

Comment: I apologize, and agree. I had about 2 minutes to do it before I had to run. I will put an explanation a bit later. I am not seeking review of my answer though... I was seeking for an idea of original question

Comment: @200_success Here you go. I updated the answer with more explanation.